# Pulling Single Post Featured Image under a Category List

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have this code in my child theme but it's pulling in the category featured image instead of the individual single posts image, when viewing a list of single post under category. The code is within a loop.

```
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail())  { ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( "full" ); ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a more thorough code sample. There's not enough context above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody gets caught up on retreiving an image outside of a single post this solution worked for me.

```
<img src="<?php $image_source = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); echo $image_source[0]; ?>">
```

The $post->ID may have to change depending on what you're working on.